# Move files (directory to directory) on a remote file system using python2.7

Tags: python

I would like to move files from one directory on a remote linux (centos) server to another directory on the same server. I am using a python27.  I'm told that a 'move' is really a copy/delete process on a remote file system, and this would appear to be the case as the (large) files take a long time to move.  Is there a quick way to move these huge files?

Answer (score 0):

[os.rename](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename)

You can use os.rename

```
os.rename("path/to/file.txt", "path/to/new/file.txt")
```

Comment: That was sure quick! Guess I'm greener that I thought. Thanks very much.

Comment: Trying os.rename as above gave me "[Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link".

Comment: Looks like new path you are choosing is on the other physical hdd. You can move objects only if they are on the same hdd.

Comment: The original path and new path should be in the same partition. check with df -h command or /etc/fstab entries to find out.

Comment: That is the problem. Will have to try to do some moving. Thank you.

Comment: Got my directories moved around, and os.rename works perfectly.  Many thanks.